# What keys are needed when passing the icons array to plugins_api()?

Tags: plugins, updates

I am building a self updater via GitHub (for a self hosted plugin) and would like to show the plugin icon on the update screen.

I have found what keys the banners use:

```
'low' => 'https://YOUR_WEBSITE/banner-772x250.jpg',
'high' => 'https://YOUR_WEBSITE/banner-1544x500.jpg'
```

But I can't find what keys the icons array needs. Ideally I want to pass one SVG icon.